# Installing a directory with a Debian Package

Tags: packaging

I want to create a Debian Package that installs a bunch of Folders to a system but I can't get it working. The Package gets created without any errors and lintian also says it's okay but installing does nothing.

The rules file looks like this:

```
<#>!/usr/bin/make -f
logs = $(CURDIR)/shell_logs/
DEST1 = /opt/Pacetutor/

build: build-stamp

build-stamp:
    dh_testdir
    touch build-stam

clean:
    dh_testdir
    dh_testroot
    rm -f build-stamp
    dh_clean

install: build clean $(logs)
    dh_testdir
    dh_testroot
    dh_prep
    dh_installdirs

mkdir -m 755 -p $(DEST1) <- this is propably optional or not needed ->

cp -r $(logs) $(DEST1) <- using mv works but thats not what I want. ->

binary-indep: build install
    dh_testdir
    dh_testroot
    dh_installchangelogs
    dh_installdocs
    dh_installexamples
    dh_installman
    dh_link
    dh_compress
    dh_fixperms
    dh_installdeb
    dh_gencontrol
    dh_md5sums
    dh_builddeb

binary-arch: build install

binary: binary-indep binary-arch
.PHONY: build clean binary-indep binary-arch binary install
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to distribute a folder like this:

> /usr/share/myfolder

First make a new folder for the debian package.
Execute this command in Terminal:

> mkdir MyDeb

Now create the debian package's control file:

> mkdir MyDeb/DEBIAN
>   gedit MyDeb/DEBIAN/control

Put necessary information in the control file. For example you can paste something like this:

> > Package: my-awesome-package
> >     Version: 1.0
> >     Architecture: amd64
> >     Maintainer: Chuck Norris `<gmail@chucknorris.com>`
> >     Description: Copies some stuff to the disk

Once done, save the control file.

Now, copy the folder you want to distribute with the debian package including it's directory structure, to the MyPackage folder, so the package folder should look like this:

> MyPackage
>   |
>   +----DEBIAN/control
>   |
>   +----usr/share/myfolder

To make the DEB package, open the Terminal and execute this command:

> dpkg -b MyPackage